# Displaying two different chart types in a single browser (plotly with python)

Tags: plotly-python

I am using plotly to display a line chart and a pie chart using python, but when i run the code it opens the charts in two separate browsers. I was wondering how I can get both charts to open in one single browser.

The code for both works but separately on different browsers. I tried using the plotly.subplots library but this is what it prints:

ValueError: Trace type 'pie' is not compatible with subplot type 'xy'
at grid position (2, 1)

See the docstring for the specs argument to plotly.subplots.make_subplots
for more information on subplot types

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using plotly.graph_objects.Pie?